# Apply Pandas Style to All Dataframes in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

In Jupyter notebooks with many Pandas Dataframes, is there a way to set default Style options for all dataframes? Essentially to avoid boilerplate.

For example [Hiding-the-Index-or-Columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Hiding-the-Index-or-Columns) with `df.style.hide_index()` for all dataframes.

Yes, I could write wrapper function, but thinking more of something like [pd.options.display](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to **inherit the pd.DataFrame** class (aka creating a **subclass of pd.DataFrame**) as described in the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas). then you can **modify its constructor to change the style**. The class should be like this:

```
class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
      # change style. you can move this into another function as well.
       self.style \
        .format(precision=3, thousands=".", decimal=",") \
        .format_index(str.upper, axis=1) \
        .hide(axis="index")
      # return an instance of CustomDataFrame
       return CustomDataFrame
```

Then, you can use this class the same as the pd.DataFrame. For example run this:

```
data = [['Mj', 27], ['Sarah', 5]]

df = CustomDataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lots of dataframes you could find dataframes in your workspace and then apply style to each one of them

```
workspace = dir() #gets all variables in workspace
for variable_name in workspace:
    excec( f'var_type=type({variable_name})' ) #since we have access to only the names of variables we'll use exec
    if var_type== pd.Dataframe():#check to see if the variable is of type dataframe
        #apply style here
```

Comment: This solution looks okay, but it only solves the problem completely if the styling only matters after every dataframe is created. Otherwise, it would have to be run on every dataframe creation, and then calling a wrapper is simpler.